Why is this question about a web service not moved to Web Apps SE?
Where to find Google Cloud security notification
Google Cloud is clearly a web service/application. This is a good question that quickly got 2 answers. I don't see anything that would get it rejected there.
Why wasn't it moved to proper SE site and got closed instead? I even got report about it rejected for "found nothing to back it up" kind of reason.
Once again, I don't understand decisions like these. This:

encourages further questions like that on this site, as people find more of them here through Googling
stops potential newer good answers from appearing in the future

I really fail to see any benefit of not moving good questions to much more proper sites. Are there any?

The close reason wasn’t selected by enough users. The best thing we could do is delete it so it could be resubmitted. Don’t believe it’s eligible to be migrated today

@Ramhound It's not too old. a mod could reopen and re-"close" as migrate to -> Web Apps

status-completed
The question was migrated to WebApps.
